# Bind Mousetrap Hotkey to certain DOM element - trigger only when div is active?

Tags: javascript, html, reactjs, dom, mousetrap

I want to bind some hotkeys to a div: Whenever the user clicks somewhere inside the div and then presses the `S` key I want to `console.log` something. However, I don't want this hotkey to be global and to be triggered each and every time the user presses `S`.

Here is what I've got so far:

```
import React from "react"
import Mousetrap from "mousetrap"

export default class Mouse extends React.Component {

  constructor(props) {
    super(props)
  }

  componentDidMount() {
    let form = document.querySelector("form")
    let m = new Mousetrap(form)

    m.bind("s", () => {
      console.log("s")
    })
  }

  componentWillUnmount() {
    // m.unbind("s", () => {
    //   console.log("s")
    // })
  }
  render() {
    return (  
        <form
          style={{ width: "300px", height: "300px", backgroundColor: "pink" }}
        >
          <input type="text" />
        </form>
    )
  }
}
```

The [Mousetrap docs](https://craig.is/killing/mice) say that I can bind my mousetrap like so:

```
var form = document.querySelector('form');
var mousetrap = new Mousetrap(form);
mousetrap.bind('mod+s', _handleSave);
mousetrap.bind('mod+z', _handleUndo);
```

As you can see in my example above, that's what I've done. It does work in this sense: whenever I type `S` while I'm in the `input` of the form, the `console.log` is being triggered. However, I don't want to use a form and neither do I want my user to be inside an input: I just want my user to have clicked on the `div`. I cannot get this to work though. I would expect it to look something like this:

```
import React from "react"
import Mousetrap from "mousetrap"

export default class Mouse extends React.Component {

  constructor(props) {
    super(props)
  }

  componentDidMount() {
    let form = document.querySelector(".trigger")
    let m = new Mousetrap(form)

    m.bind("s", () => {
      console.log("s")
    })
  }

  componentWillUnmount() {
    // m.unbind("s", () => {
    //   console.log("s")
    // })
  }
  render() {
    return ( 
        <div
          className="trigger"
          style={{ width: "300px", height: "300px", backgroundColor: "pink" }}
        >
           Click me!
        </div>
    )
  }
}
```

However, this doesn't work. Nothing is being triggered.

Edit: Also, one thing I don't quite understand in the first example above is that I am binding Mousetrap to `form`. However, the `s` hotkey is only ever triggered when I am inside the `input field` of `form`, but never when I just click on the `form` but not the `input`.

Comment: What exactly do you mean with *Whenever the user clicks somewhere inside the div and then presses the S key*. Do you want the click to be registered while the cursor is inside the `div` or does does the user really have to click first? Also should subsequent presses of `S` also be registered or does the user have to click the `div` again?

Comment: I'm sorry, I think I was unclear. I would like the user to click the div, then I highlight the border or something to show that the element is active. an while that element is active, the hotkeys should work. So there is no need to click again. I don't want hovering or anything like this to do anything. Thanks again for asking :)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The reason this happens is that the `Mousetrap` is checking if the element is focused. `div`s (or in fact any other block element like a `form`) can only be focused if they have a `tabindex` defined. Inputs can be focused without that.

But I believe you do not need to explicitly bind the `Mousetrap` to the `div` at all. All you need to do is to track the active state of your `div` and `bind()` or `unbind()` the trap accordingly.

Example:

```
class Mouse extends Component {
  state = {
    active: false,
  }

  constructor(props) {
    super(props);
    this.trap = new Mousetrap();
  }

  handleClick = () => {
    this.setState(({active}) => {
      if (!active) {
        this.trap.bind('s', this.handleKeyPress);
      } else {
        this.trap.unbind('s');
      }
      return {active: !active}
    })
  }

  handleKeyPress = () => {
    console.log('User pressed S.')
  }

  componentWillUnmount() {
    this.trap.reset();
  }

  render() {
    const {active} = this.state;

    return (
      <div 
        className={cN('trigger', {active})} 
        onClick={this.handleClick}
      >
          Click me!
      </div>
    );
  }
}
```

Demo:

[image: Edit modest-edison-hdfp7]

Comment: thanks a lot. what's the advantage of doing it like this, as opposed to binding Mousetrap + tabindex? I feel the binding solution is a bit more concise and simpler overall? What do you think?

Answer (score 0):

I think I've found the solution. Giving the `div` a `tabindex` makes it selectable, and thus, the hot key will be registered. I am not sure why this is, whether it's strictly necessary or a bit of a hacky solution. So all I had to do is:

```
<div className="trigger" tabindex="0">
```

...if anyone has a better explanation that goes in some more depth, feel free to post still, as I won't select this as the final answer for now.